# How to use final in a multi-catch statement?

Tags: java, exception

How to give final modifier to the exception when catching multiple type of exceptions in a single catch block in Java

Comment: I read his question as "how to add finally when catching multiple exceptions" indiciating the OPs confusion over the whole try/catch/finally sequence. In essence the OP seems to think you cannot use a finally block if you have used more than 1 catch block but as the OP question is really unclear I could be comepletely wrong.

Comment: Ah I think OldCurmudgeon and Chetan  understaood the OP better.

Comment: For gods sake, he just wants to explicitly declare the exception variable as final. This is not a bad question just because two people don't understand it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to mark every exception as final. Just the first one.

```
try {

} catch(final IllegalArgumentException  | ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
    e = new RuntimeException();//this will not be allowed as e is final
}
```

That being said, you don't need to mark `e` as final as it cannot be reassgined in the catch block either way when using a *multi-catch* statement.

Here's the relevant section of the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20)

> An exception parameter of a multi-catch clause is implicitly declared
>   final if it is not explicitly declared final.
>
> It is a compile-time error if an exception parameter that is
>   implicitly or explicitly declared final is assigned to within the body
>   of the catch clause.

Comment: Yeah if it's not final you still get "`The parameter e of a multi-catch block cannot be assigned`", but it's legal syntax to make it final. In my Eclipse compiler, with Java 7, I'm even allowed to refer to `e` inside an anonymous inner class if it's not `final`, so the compiler considers it final. (Only if it's a multi-catch)

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Yes. That's what I already pointed out. It seems to be final implicitly.

Answer (score 1):

The following is aimed to provide the authoritative answer.

[Java Language Specification, Java SE 7 Edition, §14.20](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20):

> An exception parameter of a multi-catch clause is implicitly declared `final` if it is not explicitly declared `final`.

As for the syntax:

```
CatchClause:
    catch ( CatchFormalParameter ) Block
CatchFormalParameter:
    VariableModifiersopt CatchType VariableDeclaratorId
```

This means that you can apply a single `final` in front of the catch type (which, in the case of multi-catch, is specified as a union of individual exception types). Your confusion may be with the fact that a multi-catch does not contain several, but just one catch variable declaration.